# testing object returned from useTranslation

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-i18next

I have the following code in my element:

**ItemComponent**

```
  const { t } = useTranslation('myjson')
  const myobject = t('myobject', { returnObjects: true })
  const renderContent = () => {
    return myobject.map(item => {
        return (<Item key={item} onClick={() => props.handleClick(item.name)}> <Icon type={item.iconType} />{item.name}</Item>)
      }
    })
  }
```

**ItemComponent.test.js**

```
it("renders without crashing", () => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    ReactDOM.render(<ItemComponent></ItemComponent>,div);
})
```

**myjson**

```
{
 "myobject":[
      
        {
          "name": "Name1",
          "iconType": "Icon1"
        },
        {
          "name": "Name2",
          "iconType": "Icon2"
        }
      ]
}
```

and a simple render test but when I run the test I receive the error `myobject.map is not a function`
is there a way to properly test this? Not sure why I am getting this error so I dont know what to research or try

I've tried `let entries = Object.keys(myobject).map((key)=>[Number(key), mybject[key]])` and then `console.log("entries",typeof entries);`

**this still returns an object**

Comment: Are you sure myobject is an array? Have you put a console.log below it and checked it?

Comment: yes, it is an array. its only giving that error for the test

Comment: ```myobject.map is not a function``` indicates that your variable does not have a map function, which in 99% of cases means it's not an array or is null or the map function was deleted. Please try:
```console.log(myobject);
console.log(myobject.map);
console.log(typeof myobject);```

after 
```const myobject = t('myobject', { returnObjects: true })```
and post your results.

Comment: okay yeah it is an object

`(2) [{…}, {…}]0:{name: "Name1", iconType: "Icon1"}1: {name: "Name1", iconType: "Icon2"}length: 2__proto__: Array(0)`
how come it maps for the UI but not the test?

Comment: [{…}, {…}]
0:{name: "Name1", iconType: "Icon1"}1: {name: "Name1", iconType: "Icon2"}
Is an array.

Comment: Didn't you write: length: 2__proto__: Array(0) ?

Comment: yeah so in the console it prints object but when I try `Object.prototype.toString.call(myobject)== '[object Array]'` that returns true...If this is whats affecting the test

Comment: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/objects-and-arrays

Try without { returnObjects: true }

Comment: without that, the items will not return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in the code I was returning the objects, I need to mock that object along with use translation:

```
const mock = {
 "myobject":[
      
        {
          "name": "Name1",
          "iconType": "Icon1"
        },
        {
          "name": "Name2",
          "iconType": "Icon2"
        }
      ]
}
```

```
jest.mock('react-i18next', ()=>({
   useTranslation: () => {
   return {
      t:(str)=>mock,
      i18:{
         changeLanguage: () => new Promise(()=>mock.myobject)
      }
    }
 }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that in the case of the variable records beeing null, your render function still tries to access the map function of your records variable, which of course ends with the 'TypeError: myobject.map is not a function' error.

Try this

```
myobject && myobject.map(item => {.....})
```

or add your array in state thene use it from state